# Printing value in a bytes class object

Tags: python, max

I have a variable like this:

```py
result =  b'{"Results": {"WebServiceOutput0": [{"Label": 7.0, "f0": 0.0, "f1": 0.0, "f2": 0.0, "f3": 0.0, "f4": 0.0, "f5": 0.0, "f6": 0.0, "f7": 0.0, "f8": 0.0, "f9": 0.0, "f10": 0.0, "f11": 0.0, "f12": 0.0, "f13": 0.0, "f14": 0.0, "f15": 0.0, "f16": 0.0, "f17": 0.0, "f18": 0.0, "f19": 0.0, "f20": 0.0, "f21": 0.0, "f22": 0.0, "f23": 0.0, "f24": 0.0, "f25": 0.0, "f26": 0.0, "f27": 0.0, "f28": 0.0, "f29": 0.0, "f30": 0.0, "f31": 0.0, "f32": 0.0, "f33": 0.0, "f34": 0.0, "f35": 0.0, "f36": 0.0, "f37": 0.0, "f38": 0.0, "f39": 0.0, "f40": 0.0, "f41": 0.0, "f42": 0.0, "f43": 0.0, "f44": 0.0, "f45": 0.0, "f46": 0.0, "f47": 0.0, "f48": 0.0, "f49": 0.0, "f50": 0.0, "f51": 0.0, "f52": 0.0, "f53": 0.0, "f54": 0.0, "f55": 0.0, "f56": 0.0, "f57": 0.0, "f58": 0.0, "f59": 0.0, "f60": 0.0, "f61": 0.0, "f62": 0.0, "f63": 0.0, "f64": 0.0, "f65": 0.0, "f66": 0.0, "f67": 0.0, "f68": 0.0, "f69": 0.0, "f70": 0.0, "f71": 0.0, "f72": 0.0, "f73": 0.0, "f74": 0.0, "f75": 0.0, "f76": 0.0, "f77": 0.0, "f78": 0.0, "f79": 0.0, "f80": 0.0, "f81": 0.0, "f82": 0.0, "f83": 0.0, "f84": 0.0, "f85": 0.0, "f86": 0.0, "f87": 0.0, "f88": 0.0, "f89": 0.0, "f90": 0.0, "f91": 0.0, "f92": 0.0, "f93": 0.0, "f94": 0.0, "f95": 0.0, "f96": 0.0, "f97": 0.0, "f98": 0.0, "f99": 0.0, "f100": 0.0, "f101": 0.0, "f102": 0.0, "f103": 0.0, "f104": 0.0, "f105": 0.0, "f106": 0.0, "f107": 0.0, "f108": 0.0, "f109": 0.0, "f110": 0.0, "f111": 0.0, "f112": 0.0, "f113": 0.0, "f114": 0.0, "f115": 0.0, "f116": 0.0, "f117": 0.0, "f118": 0.0, "f119": 0.0, "f120": 0.0, "f121": 0.0, "f122": 0.0, "f123": 0.0, "f124": 0.0, "f125": 0.0, "f126": 0.0, "f127": 0.0, "f128": 0.0, "f129": 0.0, "f130": 0.0, "f131": 0.0, "f132": 0.0, "f133": 0.0, "f134": 0.0, "f135": 0.0, "f136": 0.0, "f137": 0.0, "f138": 0.0, "f139": 0.0, "f140": 0.0, "f141": 0.0, "f142": 0.0, "f143": 0.0, "f144": 0.0, "f145": 0.0, "f146": 0.0, "f147": 0.0, "f148": 0.0, "f149": 0.0, "f150": 0.0, "f151": 0.0, "f152": 0.0, "f153": 0.0, "f154": 0.0, "f155": 0.0, "f156": 0.0, "f157": 0.0, "f158": 0.0, "f159": 0.0, "f160": 0.0, "f161": 0.0, "f162": 0.0, "f163": 0.0, "f164": 0.0, "f165": 0.0, "f166": 0.0, "f167": 0.0, "f168": 0.0, "f169": 0.0, "f170": 0.0, "f171": 0.0, "f172": 0.0, "f173": 0.0, "f174": 0.0, "f175": 0.0, "f176": 0.0, "f177": 0.0, "f178": 0.0, "f179": 0.0, "f180": 0.0, "f181": 0.0, "f182": 0.0, "f183": 0.0, "f184": 0.0, "f185": 0.0, "f186": 0.0, "f187": 0.0, "f188": 0.0, "f189": 0.0, "f190": 0.0, "f191": 0.0, "f192": 0.0, "f193": 0.0, "f194": 0.0, "f195": 0.0, "f196": 0.0, "f197": 0.0, "f198": 0.0, "f199": 0.0, "f200": 0.0, "f201": 0.0, "f202": 84.0, "f203": 185.0, "f204": 159.0, "f205": 151.0, "f206": 60.0, "f207": 36.0, "f208": 0.0, "f209": 0.0, "f210": 0.0, "f211": 0.0, "f212": 0.0, "f213": 0.0, "f214": 0.0, "f215": 0.0, "f216": 0.0, "f217": 0.0, "f218": 0.0, "f219": 0.0, "f220": 0.0, "f221": 0.0, "f222": 0.0, "f223": 0.0, "f224": 0.0, "f225": 0.0, "f226": 0.0, "f227": 0.0, "f228": 0.0, "f229": 0.0, "f230": 222.0, "f231": 254.0, "f232": 254.0, "f233": 254.0, "f234": 254.0, "f235": 241.0, "f236": 198.0, "f237": 198.0, "f238": 198.0, "f239": 198.0, "f240": 198.0, "f241": 198.0, "f242": 198.0, "f243": 198.0, "f244": 170.0, "f245": 52.0, "f246": 0.0, "f247": 0.0, "f248": 0.0, "f249": 0.0, "f250": 0.0, "f251": 0.0, "f252": 0.0, "f253": 0.0, "f254": 0.0, "f255": 0.0, "f256": 0.0, "f257": 0.0, "f258": 67.0, "f259": 114.0, "f260": 72.0, "f261": 114.0, "f262": 163.0, "f263": 227.0, "f264": 254.0, "f265": 225.0, "f266": 254.0, "f267": 254.0, "f268": 254.0, "f269": 250.0, "f270": 229.0, "f271": 254.0, "f272": 254.0, "f273": 140.0, "f274": 0.0, "f275": 0.0, "f276": 0.0, "f277": 0.0, "f278": 0.0, "f279": 0.0, "f280": 0.0, "f281": 0.0, "f282": 0.0, "f283": 0.0, "f284": 0.0, "f285": 0.0, "f286": 0.0, "f287": 0.0, "f288": 0.0, "f289": 0.0, "f290": 0.0, "f291": 17.0, "f292": 66.0, "f293": 14.0, "f294": 67.0, "f295": 67.0, "f296": 67.0, "f297": 59.0, "f298": 21.0, "f299": 236.0, "f300": 254.0, "f301": 106.0, "f302": 0.0, "f303": 0.0, "f304": 0.0, "f305": 0.0, "f306": 0.0, "f307": 0.0, "f308": 0.0, "f309": 0.0, "f310": 0.0, "f311": 0.0, "f312": 0.0, "f313": 0.0, "f314": 0.0, "f315": 0.0, "f316": 0.0, "f317": 0.0, "f318": 0.0, "f319": 0.0, "f320": 0.0, "f321": 0.0, "f322": 0.0, "f323": 0.0, "f324": 0.0, "f325": 0.0, "f326": 83.0, "f327": 253.0, "f328": 209.0, "f329": 18.0, "f330": 0.0, "f331": 0.0, "f332": 0.0, "f333": 0.0, "f334": 0.0, "f335": 0.0, "f336": 0.0, "f337": 0.0, "f338": 0.0, "f339": 0.0, "f340": 0.0, "f341": 0.0, "f342": 0.0, "f343": 0.0, "f344": 0.0, "f345": 0.0, "f346": 0.0, "f347": 0.0, "f348": 0.0, "f349": 0.0, "f350": 0.0, "f351": 0.0, "f352": 0.0, "f353": 22.0, "f354": 233.0, "f355": 255.0, "f356": 83.0, "f357": 0.0, "f358": 0.0, "f359": 0.0, "f360": 0.0, "f361": 0.0, "f362": 0.0, "f363": 0.0, "f364": 0.0, "f365": 0.0, "f366": 0.0, "f367": 0.0, "f368": 0.0, "f369": 0.0, "f370": 0.0, "f371": 0.0, "f372": 0.0, "f373": 0.0, "f374": 0.0, "f375": 0.0, "f376": 0.0, "f377": 0.0, "f378": 0.0, "f379": 0.0, "f380": 0.0, "f381": 129.0, "f382": 254.0, "f383": 238.0, "f384": 44.0, "f385": 0.0, "f386": 0.0, "f387": 0.0, "f388": 0.0, "f389": 0.0, "f390": 0.0, "f391": 0.0, "f392": 0.0, "f393": 0.0, "f394": 0.0, "f395": 0.0, "f396": 0.0, "f397": 0.0, "f398": 0.0, "f399": 0.0, "f400": 0.0, "f401": 0.0, "f402": 0.0, "f403": 0.0, "f404": 0.0, "f405": 0.0, "f406": 0.0, "f407": 0.0, "f408": 59.0, "f409": 249.0, "f410": 254.0, "f411": 62.0, "f412": 0.0, "f413": 0.0, "f414": 0.0, "f415": 0.0, "f416": 0.0, "f417": 0.0, "f418": 0.0, "f419": 0.0, "f420": 0.0, "f421": 0.0, "f422": 0.0, "f423": 0.0, "f424": 0.0, "f425": 0.0, "f426": 0.0, "f427": 0.0, "f428": 0.0, "f429": 0.0, "f430": 0.0, "f431": 0.0, "f432": 0.0, "f433": 0.0, "f434": 0.0, "f435": 0.0, "f436": 133.0, "f437": 254.0, "f438": 187.0, "f439": 5.0, "f440": 0.0, "f441": 0.0, "f442": 0.0, "f443": 0.0, "f444": 0.0, "f445": 0.0, "f446": 0.0, "f447": 0.0, "f448": 0.0, "f449": 0.0, "f450": 0.0, "f451": 0.0, "f452": 0.0, "f453": 0.0, "f454": 0.0, "f455": 0.0, "f456": 0.0, "f457": 0.0, "f458": 0.0, "f459": 0.0, "f460": 0.0, "f461": 0.0, "f462": 0.0, "f463": 9.0, "f464": 205.0, "f465": 248.0, "f466": 58.0, "f467": 0.0, "f468": 0.0, "f469": 0.0, "f470": 0.0, "f471": 0.0, "f472": 0.0, "f473": 0.0, "f474": 0.0, "f475": 0.0, "f476": 0.0, "f477": 0.0, "f478": 0.0, "f479": 0.0, "f480": 0.0, "f481": 0.0, "f482": 0.0, "f483": 0.0, "f484": 0.0, "f485": 0.0, "f486": 0.0, "f487": 0.0, "f488": 0.0, "f489": 0.0, "f490": 0.0, "f491": 126.0, "f492": 254.0, "f493": 182.0, "f494": 0.0, "f495": 0.0, "f496": 0.0, "f497": 0.0, "f498": 0.0, "f499": 0.0, "f500": 0.0, "f501": 0.0, "f502": 0.0, "f503": 0.0, "f504": 0.0, "f505": 0.0, "f506": 0.0, "f507": 0.0, "f508": 0.0, "f509": 0.0, "f510": 0.0, "f511": 0.0, "f512": 0.0, "f513": 0.0, "f514": 0.0, "f515": 0.0, "f516": 0.0, "f517": 0.0, "f518": 75.0, "f519": 251.0, "f520": 240.0, "f521": 57.0, "f522": 0.0, "f523": 0.0, "f524": 0.0, "f525": 0.0, "f526": 0.0, "f527": 0.0, "f528": 0.0, "f529": 0.0, "f530": 0.0, "f531": 0.0, "f532": 0.0, "f533": 0.0, "f534": 0.0, "f535": 0.0, "f536": 0.0, "f537": 0.0, "f538": 0.0, "f539": 0.0, "f540": 0.0, "f541": 0.0, "f542": 0.0, "f543": 0.0, "f544": 0.0, "f545": 19.0, "f546": 221.0, "f547": 254.0, "f548": 166.0, "f549": 0.0, "f550": 0.0, "f551": 0.0, "f552": 0.0, "f553": 0.0, "f554": 0.0, "f555": 0.0, "f556": 0.0, "f557": 0.0, "f558": 0.0, "f559": 0.0, "f560": 0.0, "f561": 0.0, "f562": 0.0, "f563": 0.0, "f564": 0.0, "f565": 0.0, "f566": 0.0, "f567": 0.0, "f568": 0.0, "f569": 0.0, "f570": 0.0, "f571": 0.0, "f572": 3.0, "f573": 203.0, "f574": 254.0, "f575": 219.0, "f576": 35.0, "f577": 0.0, "f578": 0.0, "f579": 0.0, "f580": 0.0, "f581": 0.0, "f582": 0.0, "f583": 0.0, "f584": 0.0, "f585": 0.0, "f586": 0.0, "f587": 0.0, "f588": 0.0, "f589": 0.0, "f590": 0.0, "f591": 0.0, "f592": 0.0, "f593": 0.0, "f594": 0.0, "f595": 0.0, "f596": 0.0, "f597": 0.0, "f598": 0.0, "f599": 0.0, "f600": 38.0, "f601": 254.0, "f602": 254.0, "f603": 77.0, "f604": 0.0, "f605": 0.0, "f606": 0.0, "f607": 0.0, "f608": 0.0, "f609": 0.0, "f610": 0.0, "f611": 0.0, "f612": 0.0, "f613": 0.0, "f614": 0.0, "f615": 0.0, "f616": 0.0, "f617": 0.0, "f618": 0.0, "f619": 0.0, "f620": 0.0, "f621": 0.0, "f622": 0.0, "f623": 0.0, "f624": 0.0, "f625": 0.0, "f626": 0.0, "f627": 31.0, "f628": 224.0, "f629": 254.0, "f630": 115.0, "f631": 1.0, "f632": 0.0, "f633": 0.0, "f634": 0.0, "f635": 0.0, "f636": 0.0, "f637": 0.0, "f638": 0.0, "f639": 0.0, "f640": 0.0, "f641": 0.0, "f642": 0.0, "f643": 0.0, "f644": 0.0, "f645": 0.0, "f646": 0.0, "f647": 0.0, "f648": 0.0, "f649": 0.0, "f650": 0.0, "f651": 0.0, "f652": 0.0, "f653": 0.0, "f654": 0.0, "f655": 133.0, "f656": 254.0, "f657": 254.0, "f658": 52.0, "f659": 0.0, "f660": 0.0, "f661": 0.0, "f662": 0.0, "f663": 0.0, "f664": 0.0, "f665": 0.0, "f666": 0.0, "f667": 0.0, "f668": 0.0, "f669": 0.0, "f670": 0.0, "f671": 0.0, "f672": 0.0, "f673": 0.0, "f674": 0.0, "f675": 0.0, "f676": 0.0, "f677": 0.0, "f678": 0.0, "f679": 0.0, "f680": 0.0, "f681": 0.0, "f682": 61.0, "f683": 242.0, "f684": 254.0, "f685": 254.0, "f686": 52.0, "f687": 0.0, "f688": 0.0, "f689": 0.0, "f690": 0.0, "f691": 0.0, "f692": 0.0, "f693": 0.0, "f694": 0.0, "f695": 0.0, "f696": 0.0, "f697": 0.0, "f698": 0.0, "f699": 0.0, "f700": 0.0, "f701": 0.0, "f702": 0.0, "f703": 0.0, "f704": 0.0, "f705": 0.0, "f706": 0.0, "f707": 0.0, "f708": 0.0, "f709": 0.0, "f710": 121.0, "f711": 254.0, "f712": 254.0, "f713": 219.0, "f714": 40.0, "f715": 0.0, "f716": 0.0, "f717": 0.0, "f718": 0.0, "f719": 0.0, "f720": 0.0, "f721": 0.0, "f722": 0.0, "f723": 0.0, "f724": 0.0, "f725": 0.0, "f726": 0.0, "f727": 0.0, "f728": 0.0, "f729": 0.0, "f730": 0.0, "f731": 0.0, "f732": 0.0, "f733": 0.0, "f734": 0.0, "f735": 0.0, "f736": 0.0, "f737": 0.0, "f738": 121.0, "f739": 254.0, "f740": 207.0, "f741": 18.0, "f742": 0.0, "f743": 0.0, "f744": 0.0, "f745": 0.0, "f746": 0.0, "f747": 0.0, "f748": 0.0, "f749": 0.0, "f750": 0.0, "f751": 0.0, "f752": 0.0, "f753": 0.0, "f754": 0.0, "f755": 0.0, "f756": 0.0, "f757": 0.0, "f758": 0.0, "f759": 0.0, "f760": 0.0, "f761": 0.0, "f762": 0.0, "f763": 0.0, "f764": 0.0, "f765": 0.0, "f766": 0.0, "f767": 0.0, "f768": 0.0, "f769": 0.0, "f770": 0.0, "f771": 0.0, "f772": 0.0, "f773": 0.0, "f774": 0.0, "f775": 0.0, "f776": 0.0, "f777": 0.0, "f778": 0.0, "f779": 0.0, "f780": 0.0, "f781": 0.0, "f782": 0.0, "f783": 0.0, "Scored Probabilities_0": 1.7306872933250431e-07, "Scored Probabilities_1": 3.3177526751193424e-09, "Scored Probabilities_2": 6.772526557729492e-07, "Scored Probabilities_3": 5.018638683008445e-05, "Scored Probabilities_4": 3.5781842069911e-11, "Scored Probabilities_5": 4.2981825008019914e-08, "Scored Probabilities_6": 6.350046754243676e-14, "Scored Probabilities_7": 0.9999483485221952, "Scored Probabilities_8": 1.3431149602373933e-07, "Scored Probabilities_9": 4.341226706439234e-07, "Scored Labels": 7.0}]}}'
```

This is the first time I've seen this type of object. How can I get the value of `Scored Probabilities_n` (`n` is from `0` to `9`) and the `Scored Labels`? Furthermore, can I get the maximum value (in this case it should be `"Scored Probabilities_7": 0.9999483485221952`)?

Even when I tried some ways to get the highest value of the variable but it's somehow difficult:

```py
print(max(result))
125
```

As I can see, there's no `125` value in the variable. So does it mean the normal calculation can not be done on this too? I expected to see the answer on my question above. Thank you!

Comment: This is a bytes object (kinda like a string). Search "how to convert bytes to json"

Comment: Convert the bytes array to a dictionary with `d = json.loads(result)` and then you can access the dictionary keys in the usual way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
import json
d = json.loads(result.decode('utf-8'))['Results']['WebServiceOutput0'][0]

d['Scored Labels']
# 1.7306872933250431e-07

max_p = max((k for k in d if k.startswith('Scored Probabilities_')), key=d.get)
# 'Scored Probabilities_7'

d[max_p]
# 0.9999483485221952
```